# What happens to the session if i keep below condition in update strategy transformation in informatica?

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

What happens to the session if i keep below condition in update strategy transformation in PowerCenter?

```
IIF(Col1=Col2,100,dd_update)
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate your query?

Comment: Mapping flow is like below. Source --> Source Qualifier --> Update strategy --> Target.  I want to update the target records with source records and using update strategy for the same. in Updated strategy, im having condition like  iif(col1=col2,dd_update,dd_insert). but instead of dd_update, i want to keep 100. i want to know what will happen. as this was asked in one of my recent interviews.

Comment: https://it.toolbox.com/question/what-is-the-default-expression-for-update-strategy-092313 .... this link might help

Comment: Thanks Shahrukhkhan Pathan...I think this is useful

Answer (score 0):

The integer evuivalents of the `DD_` constants are:

- `DD_INSERT` - 0
- `DD_UPDATE` - 1
- `DD_DELETE` - 2
- `DD_REJECT` - 3

The default operation is INSERT, so if you specify an invalid value like 100, the PowerCenter Integration Service will insert the rows flagged this way.